# Impossible to signed android apk with Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, signed-apk

I have created an application with Expo but I have some difficulties to upload it to Google Play because everytime the signed apk not corresponding to uploaded_certificate.

First, I activated the app signing by Google Play with my keystore I generate a file with a specific jks file.

Secondly, I follow this [tutorial](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/app-signing/) to attempt to signed my apk 
I tried to execute this line `expo opt-in-google-play-signing`, but when the dialog asked me if app signing is enabled I said yes and nothing happened.

So I replace my jks with the same I use in first step and when I tried with the apk generated signed I get this error message :

`You have imported an APK that is not signed with the import certificate. You must use the same certificate. The import certificate bears the following fingerprint`

Thanks for your help

Comment: There could definitely be more information on Expo's docs about this. Both iOS and Android's signing processes are very complicated. Glad you figured it out. Make sure you save all your passwords, keys, secrets and all your files in a safe location (password manager preferred) because if you need to change to a different provider or have a need to regenerate its much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I use this command line `expo build:android --clear-credentials` to reset my credentials. And after when the dialog asks to select between 
`1) Let Expo handle the process!
2) I want to upload my own keystore!`

I should be selected the 2nd and choose the path to my keystore. After that when I upload the apk everything works !

Comment: how to give path

Comment: Hi, I did as you say you did. I gave the keystore path, alias, keystore password, and password, but then I get the error - `Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace`